# JSON Count and Sort with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This is my JSON data:

```
{
  "EF": [
    {
      "OP": "op1",
      "pound": 2000,
      "Date": "2012-1-13T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "OP": "op1",
      "pound": 1800,
      "Date": "2014-12-6T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "OP": "op2",
      "pound": 300,
      "Date": "2013-6-1T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to **Count** each parameter value and **Sort** them from largest to smallest to have a table like this:

> OP : op1 (2), OP2 (1) Pound: 2000, 1800, 300 Date:
>   2014-12-6T00:00:00.000Z, 2013-6-1T00:00:00.000Z,
>   2012-1-13T00:00:00.000Z

I tried to use d3.nest() but I didnot have much success with it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Largest to smallest what?

Comment: first, you need to parse the JSON string to a plain ol' javascript object - then you can sort or do whatever ... your "table" doesn't look at all tabular by the way

Comment: I want to count the number of occurrence for string field ("OP"). For numeric and date fields i simply want to find to sort the data

Comment: Can you possibly clean up that output data? How **exactly** do you want it to look at the end of the operation?

Comment: Database contains multiple fields (string, numeric, and date fields). For string fields I want to count the occurrence of each string and list it. for numeric and date I want to sort them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//JSON from db?
var json = {
  "EF": [{
    "OP": "op1",
    "pound": 2000,
    "Date": "2012-1-13T00:00:00.000Z"
  }, {
    "OP": "op1",
    "pound": 1800,
    "Date": "2014-12-6T00:00:00.000Z"
  }, {
    "OP": "op2",
    "pound": 300,
    "Date": "2013-6-1T00:00:00.000Z"
  }]
};

//Sort based on pound
json.EF.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.pound < b.pound) return 1;
  if (a.pound > b.pound) return -1;
  return 0;
});

var hash = {}; //Keep track of counts
//Count the values
for (var i in json.EF) {
  var obj = json.EF[i];
  if (hash[obj.OP]) {
    hash[obj.OP] += 1;
  } else {
    hash[obj.OP] = 1;
  }
}

//Sorted
console.log("SORTED:", json);
console.log("COUNTS:", hash);

//Now, when you loop through the json to display the values, just check the counts and display them
```

Comment: Sweet. I get the idea what to do now. Thanks Matt

Comment: @Amir Not a problem. :)

Comment: ok this solution doesn't work for my large database. I have 10,000 records with different OP values. what do you suggest? Thanks again!

Comment: What database are you using? You should be able to do a count via a query, same with a sort.

Comment: by Database I meant JSON data with 10,000 records.

Comment: Okay, so 10000 records means any kind of sorting is going to take a very long time. The way I'm sorting is linear, same with counting, meaning it'll have to go through the json twice so 20,000 loops.

Is this JSON data static? Is there a reason your using a large json file rather then storing it in some sort of DB? A database would allow you to easily query the information you need. Rather then loading a massive json file into memory and doing the sort example I gave.

Comment: Well my data is sitting in JSON file and I am visualizing it using D3.js. When I first started, JSON file was small but then it grow large and large. Database may be a good idea

Comment: Throwing 10,000 records at a visualization might cause a little bit of performance issues. Yeah, breaking it up into smaller chunks that can be visualized indendently might be the best way to go. Maybe visualize based on an aggregation of data grouped by date ranges. Hope that helps.